# In SQL-Server for adding DEFAULT constraint, is it compulsory to give constraint name? if NO then what would be the statement for it

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER TABLE Persons ADD CONSTRAINT df_City  DEFAULT 'Sandnes' FOR City;
```

Comment: The [fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql) covers this, and the answer is no; in a standalone statement the constraint name is compulsory. This is a *good thing*, because constraints *must* have a name, and if you don't specify one the system ends up generating one for you -- in such a way that you won't be able to refer to it later if it ever needs to be dropped (at least not without looking it up first, which is very inconvenient to do from a script). Adopt an easy convention, like `DF_<TableName>_<Column>`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not required to name them at all. I usually create them like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    DWCreatedDate datetime DEFAULT(GETDATE())
)
```

As @Jeroen Mostert specifies, though, it'll end up with the constraint being named by SQL Server itself, rather than having something obvious. It typically will include a random number added to the name.